# Computing $\log(2)$ as a period

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I would like to prove
$$\int_0^1 \frac{xdx}{\log\frac{1}{1-x}} = \log 2$$
and for this I tried to make the change of variables $x \mapsto 2x-x^2$ in
$$\int_{2\varepsilon - \varepsilon^2}^1 \frac{dx}{\log (1-x)}$$
but I don't see the relation (and maybe I miss a classical integral representation of $\log 2$ too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $x\mapsto 1-x$ instead (this substitution preserves the interval of integration):

$$\int_0^1\frac{x\,\mathrm{d}x}{\log\frac1{1-x}}\overset{x\mapsto 1-x}=-\int_0^1\frac{1-x}{\log(x)}\ \mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1\frac{x-1}{\log x}\ \mathrm{d}x$$

The remaining integral is easily recognized as [Frullani type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral) after enforcing $x\mapsto e^{-x}$:

$$\int_0^1\frac{x-1}{\log x}\ \mathrm{d}x\overset{x\mapsto e^{-x}}=\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}-e^{-2x}}{x}\ \mathrm{d} x=\log2$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $x \mapsto 1-x$ and use $\displaystyle \int_0^1 x^{\lambda} \, \mathrm{d}\lambda = \frac{x-1}{\log{x}}.$

$$\displaystyle \displaystyle \begin{aligned}I & = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1}{\log{x}}\;{dx} \\&= \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\lambda}\;{d\lambda}\;{dx} \\& =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\lambda}\;{dx}\;{d\lambda} \\&= \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+\lambda}\;{d\lambda} \\&= \log{2}.\end{aligned}$$

Comment: (+1) That's the direct alternative which I, of course, missed as I've nearly every single time I applied Frullani. However, proving Frullani is (AFAIK) in general easier than proving Fubini-Tonelli.

Comment: @mrtaurho I agree. Frullani is really the better method in general.